# Use an array to check data

Tags: javascript

I have an array which im using to loop through divs i have stored in variables... but i want to use the values in the array as part of the variable names i wish to check.

Heres an example of what im trying to do:

```
 var data_one = document.getElementById('test'),
     data_two = document.getElementById('test2'),
     array = ['one','two'];


 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { //error on this line

   if(parseInt(data_+array[i]) < 3){
         //do something
    }

 }
```

But i get this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: data_ is not defined`

Is there a way to use the array values to act like the variable name some how?

Comment: I think using an object would work: you can read an object's key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
var data = [ 
    document.getElementById('test'), 
    document.getElementById('test2') 
];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(parseInt(data[i]) < 3){
         //do something
    }
}
```

or with an object:

```
var data = { 
    'one': document.getElementById('test'), 
    'two': document.getElementById('test2') 
};

for (var i in data) {
    if(parseInt(data[i]) < 3){
         //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn its so obvious now ! Why didn't that occur to me!

Answer (score 0):

Use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) which evaluates string as javascript code

```
var data_a = 12;
var b = "a";

alert("data_"+b);       // alerts data_a
alert(eval("data_"+b));  // alerts 12
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ftGhd/

Comment: While `eval` would work, it is a nasty solution to the problem.  The performance hit of firing up a complete compiler just to calculate an offset is insane.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I just said one of the solution as per his code ... We can give a solutions for this in many ways .. What i did is "In his own way"

Answer (score -2):

```
var data_one = document.getElementById('test'),
     data_two = document.getElementById('test2'),
     array = ['one','two'];


 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   eval("var curr_array = data_"+array[i]);
   if(parseInt(curr_array) < 3){
         //do something
    }

 }
```

Comment: `eval` spotted, kill it with fire

Comment: LOL @RC was about to say the same thing!

Comment: You can always appeal to `this` or the global object: `parseInt(this["data_" + array[i]])`

Comment: Not sure thats the most effective way =/ @Nirk